# SQL query returning elements from multiple tables that passes certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Given these tables:

```
movie (id, name, year)
actor (id, fname, lname)
cast  (movieid, actorid, role)
```

I want to find the names of actors that had 3 or more distinct roles in the same movies in 2013. I need the actors name, movie names, and the number of roles they had in that movie.

So far I have:

```
select a.fname, a.lname (select m.name (select count(distinct c.role)
                                        from actor a, cast c
                                        where a.id=c.actorid and                                           
                                              c.movieid=m.id and m.year =  
                                                                    2013 )
                          from movie m)
group by a.fname, a.lname
having count(distinct c.roles) >=3
```

My intuition is that the inner most query will compute the number of roles each actor played for a movie in 2013. The next level query will select the name of those movies and the outermost will return the name of the actors that had 3 or more distinct roles in each movie.

For example:

movies

```
id      name       year
1        a           1990
2       b          2013      
3       c         2000
4       d         1998
5       e         2013
```

actor

```
id       fname      lname  
1       bob        dylan
2       angelina   jolie
3       meghan     fox
5       jane       doe
```

casts

```
actorid    movieid     role
1           2         nanny
1           2         maid
1           2          butler
2          3           main
1          5           baby
1          5           kid
1          5           teen
4           2          main
5           4          support
```

the query should return the following:

```
a.fname    a.lname      m.name     count(distinct roles in movie)
bob         dylan        a                3
bob         dylan        e                3
```

There may be a actor that had 3 or more distinct roles in multiple movies in the year 2013. So bob played 3 roles in movie a and 3 roles in movie e both of which are from 2013, the results should list bob twice once with movie a and count of 3 and another with movie e count of 3.

Comment: If you are shaky on sub-queries and joins, I suggest going through [SQL Zoo](http://sqlzoo.net/) tutorial.

Comment: This homework question wants you to do two simple joins.

Comment: Why are we still using the old-school comma separator for join operations? What year *is* this?

Comment: The specification isn't clear. This is where some *sample data* and the *expected result* would help clarify the specification. Individual actors that had three or more roles in the same movie? Or, a group of actors that were in the same movie? The specification is not at all clear. And without a specification, we'd just be throwing SQL together.

Comment: With my answer I attempt to solve for individual actors having three or more roles in the same movie.

Comment: There may be a actor that had 3 or more distinct roles in multiple movies in the year 2013. So if bob played 3 roles in movie a and 5 roles in movie b both of which are from 2013, the results should list bob twice once with movie a and count of 3 and another with movie b count of 5

Comment: 1996 Eddie Murphy The Nutty Professor (7); 1999 Mike Myers The Spy Who Shagged Me (3); 2002 Mike Myers Goldmember (4); ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:

```
SELECT actor.fname, actor.lname, movie.name, count(role)
FROM cast
JOIN movie ON movieid = movie.id
JOIN actor ON actorid = actor.id
WHERE movie.year = 2013
GROUP BY actorid, movieid
HAVING count(role) >= 3;
```

<strike>I hope it does.</strike> It seems to do now.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you for your comment. I edited my answer.

Comment: I forgot that group by could include multiple attributes. Thank you.

Comment: @Misohappi that I could help!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a.fname, 
       a.lname,
       m.name, 
       COUNT( DISTINCT c.role ) AS cnt_roles_per_movie
  FROM actor a, 
       cast c,
       ( SELECT id,name 
           FROM movie
          WHERE year = 2013
       ) m
 WHERE a.id = c.actorid
   AND m.id = c.movieid
GROUP BY a.fname,a.lname
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT c.role ) >= 3
;
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the need for the inline view `m` (why we would prefer that over just a join to the movie table. I don't believe this returns the resultset specified by OP.  The value returned for movie name (m.name) is indeterminate... it will be from some row in movie in the group, but it will return only one of the movie names.

Comment: I am selecting all movies for the year 2013 to minimize the cost of the query.

Comment: In MySQL, the inline view will likely *increase* the cost of the query vs. a join to the movie table with a predicate (condition in the WHERE clause), assuming suitable indexes are available. (The inline view is going to be materialized as a derived table without any index.).